# nonnegative Riemann-integrable function, infimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$f$ is a nonnegative Riemann-integrable function on $(0,1)$ and $f(x)\ge\sqrt{\int_0^xf(t)dt}$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Find $\inf\frac{f(x)}{x}$

I have no idea how to work out the assumption, for equality I found nontrivial solution among linear functions: $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: yes of course, this is the trivial solution

Comment: Just to make it clear, you are looking for $$\inf_f \frac{f(x)}{x},$$ right? Otherwise $\inf_{x\in(0,1)}\frac{f(x)}{x}$, despite being always $\geq\frac{1}{2}$, depends on $f$.

Comment: Following the discussion had with @JackD'Aurizio, it would be nice if the OP clarified whether he looks for $\inf \limits _f \inf \limits _x \frac {f(x)} x$ or for (the $f$-depending) $\inf \limits _x \frac {f(x)} x$. As it is currently written, the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

$$ f(x) \geq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt} \geq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{x}t\cdot \inf_{t\in(0,1)}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sqrt{\inf_{t\in(0,1)}\frac{f(t)}{t}}$$
leads to:
$$ \frac{f(x)}{x}\geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\inf_{t\in(0,1)}\frac{f(t)}{t}}$$
from which:
$$ \inf_{t\in(0,1)}\frac{f(t)}{t}\geq\frac{1}{2} $$
follows. As you noticed, equality is attained by $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, hence the last inequality, in general, cannot be improved.

Comment: I do not think that this is the last word on the problem: yes, $\inf \frac {f(x)} x \geq \frac 1 2$, but for various functions it could be strictly higher than that. The fact that equality is attained for $\frac x 2$ does not mean that it is attained for every function.

Comment: @AlexM.: you got it the wrong way. The first lines imply that $\inf \geq\frac{1}{2}$ holds, for every function. One may wonder if a stronger inequality holds, say $\inf\geq 1$, but in such a case $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: You got it the wrong way :). Who says that $\inf \frac {f(x)} x$ must be independent of $f$? Yes, for $\frac x 2$ it is $\frac 1 2$, but for some other function it might be $\frac 3 4$. Yes, all of them are $\geq \frac 1 2$, but each one depends in principle on $f$.

Comment: Take $f(x)=1$. Then the given inequality is rewritten as $1 \geq \sqrt x$ for $x \in (0,1)$ which is true, so $f=1$ satisfies the hypotheses. But then $\inf \limits _{x \in (0,1)} \frac 1 x = 1$, not $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @AlexM.  And so? You have found a function that satisfies a stronger inequality, good. But in general, we cannot state something stronger than $\inf \geq\frac{1}{2}$, and $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ proves it.

Comment: Jack, you are in love with your solution :) that you cannot see clearly anymore: the question does not ask to find $\inf \limits _f \{\inf \limits _x \frac {f(x)} x \}$ (which in this case would rightfully be $\frac 1 2$); the question asks to find, for every $f$, $\inf \limits _x \frac {f(x)} x$, which is a totally different business. More clearly, we are required to find the function $f \mapsto \inf \limits _x \frac {f(x)} x$; you have only found its infimum - which is not bad, but this wasn't the requirement.

Comment: @AlexM.: if the problem was that, every function would have its infimum. In any case, greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. Your solution does not even prove that.

Comment: Yes, finally we can understand each other. "That" is the problem. And my answer begins with the words "this is not an answer", i.e. I do not claim to give a solution. I just provide a bound that in some cases is finer than yours (while, in other cases, yours is finer than mine). For the constant function $1$ my bound is finer than yours, for instance. Now, you finally see where the difficulty of the original question is (asuming that the OP correctly formulated his thoughts). Your solution is nice, but it answers a different question than the one asked. No need to feel offended by that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it is too long for a comment: we have $$f(x) \geq \sqrt {\int \limits _0 ^x f(t) \space \mathbb d t} \geq \sqrt {\int \limits _0 ^x \inf \limits _{t \in (0,1)} f(t) \space \mathbb d t} = \sqrt {x \inf \limits _{t \in (0,1)} f(t)}$$, so $\frac {f(x)} x \geq \sqrt \frac {\inf \limits _{t \in (0,1)} f(t)} x$, which implies $\inf \limits _{x \in (0,1)} \frac {f(x)} x \geq \sqrt {\inf \limits _{t \in (0,1)} f(t)}$.

Comment: So if $f$ i continuous and $f(0)=0$, you are just stating something trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: And if $f$ is not continuous, or $f(0) > 0$, is it trivial anylonger?

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: No need to be so harsh, really. Don't take a neutral discussion personally.